# How to use autoFill with keychain access in WKWebView

Tags: swift, wkwebview, keychain, autofill

In i0S 11.0 introduce username and password autofill in apps but I found post on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/82f0ez/favourite_ios_113_feature_keychain_for_webview/) that it is possible to use it also in WKWebView but couldn't find any description how to use it, how to let WKWebView that that specific inputView is this for password and username and display autoFill above the keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost sure this has been answered elsewhere, but [Enabling Password AutoFill on an HTML Input Element](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_an_html_input_element) from Apple's docs is what you need.

TL;DR:

```html
<input id="user-text-field" type="email" autocomplete="username"/>
<input id="password-text-field" type="password" autocomplete="current-password"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be no direct documentation on this for wkWebView on Apple Dev site. Frenchie's answer and reference are for UI View only.
wkWebView may require the app to have domain trust entitlement before the "Save Password" dialogue is presented, but this is just speculation. Without domain entitlement, the password autofill prompt is generated, however only generically, and not with the appropriate domain credentials suggested - this tell us that autofill *is* triggered, but it is not definitively recognizing the domain within the wkwebview. Saving password to autofill/keychain works in Safari, but is not firing in wkwebview. We will be experimenting with domain trust to see if that will allow autofill to work the same as it does in Safari/SafariViewController.

Comment: What did you end up finding on this?

Comment: Domain Entitlement properly set-up between App and wkWebView serving site(domain) allowed keychain/auto-fill to recognize the user/pass. However, this only worked for auto-fill of existing credentials. The "save password" is not prompted within wkWebView despite the Domain Entitlement, unless I am missing something else required. Still researching.

Comment: @JeffZ Any more details?

Answer (score 1):

We have the same problem. We use Swift and WkWebView for a hyprid app.

It seems to be documented in "[Password AutoFill](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/)". According to the documentation you need two things:

> 1. Set up your app’s associated domains.

We have set up an associated domain as we need this for universal Links anyway. The universal links are working in our app. So this is fulfilled.

> 2. Set the correct AutoFill type on relevant text fields. ... For a web app, see Enabling Password AutoFill on an HTML Input Element.

We have set up the HTML parameters as documented in "[Enabling Password AutoFill on an HTML Input Element](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_an_html_input_element)"

When I visit our registration page with safari: it will offer me a safe password and offers me to save this password (or my own custom password) in the Keychain of my iPhone.

This does NOT happen when I go to the same registration page in my hybrid app.
But the hybrid App does use already available credentials in the iOS keyChain when I try to login.

I think achieving more is not possible with WkWebView which is a) very annoying and b) should be documented